# Laravel 4 Carbon Format with if statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, php-carbon

Does anyone know how I could get this to work.
My database has some null dates, so I would like to return as empty space.

I currently have this.
`{{ Carbon::parse($chauffeur->roadTestCert)->format('m/d/Y') }}`
and from what I read about the blade template is that you can use "or 'message'" after it.
I did this.
`{{ Carbon::parse($chauffeur->roadTestCert)->format('m/d/Y') or '' }}`
in hopes to just show empty space but I get a "1" instead.

Anyone know why and/or how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should rather do it using simple condition:

```
@if ($chauffeur->roadTestCert !== null)
   {{ Carbon::parse($chauffeur->roadTestCert)->format('m/d/Y') }}
@endif
```

Comment: @Allen If you have new question, you should asked one in different thread